# pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle: it's not the same object as

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, metaclass

We're trying to use metaclasses for a custom backend selection (`multiprocessing.Process` or `threading.Thread`). The rationale behind this implementation is to extend Process/Thread's functionalities for our custom usage. While the following code works for `fork` (default in unix). But for `spawn` (default in windows), I get an error.

```
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.DProcess'>: it's not the same object as __main__.DProcess
```

The error comes from the [pickle module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/pickle.py#L1074) as the objects are not same.

```
obj: <class '__main__.DProcess'>, 
obj.__dict__: {'__module__': '__main__', 'run': <function DProcess.run at 0x7fa76ccd97a0>, '__doc__': None, '__slotnames__': []}
hash(obj): 5875061359185

obj2: <class '__main__.DProcess'>, 
obj2.__dict__: {'__module__': '__main__', 'run': <function DProcess.run at 0x7fa76ccd97a0>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'DProcess' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'DProcess' objects>, '__doc__': None}, 
hash(obj2): 5875061305336
```

I'm not quite sure what's happening here.

1. Why are the 2 objects different? Executing `save_global` from pickle module on the class object doesn't fail. Is it because of the `__call__` implementation? How do I fix it?
2. Why is this check not performed for fork?

Here's the code:

```py
class Backend(type):
    _cache = {}

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        _cls = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
        # store the subclass dict to be used during __call__
        Backend._cache.update(
            {name: {'cls': cls, 'name': name, 'bases': bases, 'dct': dct}}
        )
        return _cls

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs) -> 'Backend':
        try:
            # check arg & select the base class
            if args[0] == 'process':
                import multiprocessing
                _cls = multiprocessing.Process
            elif args[0] == 'thread':
                import threading
                _cls = threading.Thread
        except KeyError:
            print('Please pass process or thread as the 1st arg')

        for c in cls.mro()[-2::-1]:
            # pick args from __new__ and call type()
            arg_cls = Backend._cache[c.__name__]['cls']
            arg_name = Backend._cache[c.__name__]['name']
            arg_dct = Backend._cache[c.__name__]['dct']
            _cls = super().__new__(arg_cls, arg_name, (_cls,), arg_dct)

        return type.__call__(_cls, *args[1:], **kwargs)


class DProcess(metaclass=Backend):
    def run(self):
        print('we are in dprocess')
        super().run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing import set_start_method as _set_start_method
    _set_start_method('spawn')
    DProcess('process').start()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a metaclass, you should not use it- - there are better patterns for what you want. First f all: do you really need to *inherit* from Thread or Process?? Maybe a better choice is just have these as an associated attribute on your DProcess class, and - it can then work as an ordinary class attribute.

Since the important interface for both is basically set the target callable, `start` and `join`  you can either create proxy methods for those, or just call the method directly in the class attribute.

I.E., your design can likely work just like this

```
class DProcess():
    def __init__(self, backend):
        if backend == "process":
            self.backend_cls = multiprocessing.Process
        elif backend == "thread":
            self.backend_cls = threading.Thread
            
        self.worker = self.backend_cls(target=self.run)
        
    def start(self):
        
        self.worker.start()
        # or just call "instance.worker.start()" from outside
        
    def join(self):
        return self.worker.join()
    
    def run(self):
        print('we are in dprocess')
        super().run()
```

Now, the reasons your original code fail are because it is wrong: you actually do create a *new* sibling class to DProcess on each instantiation of
DProcess, dynamically, calling `super().__new__` on the metaclass `__call__`.

So, the `class DProcess` declared in your core is one class. But each time you try to instntiate it, a new class objct is created, and that is instantiated - that is what pickle is complaining about. (and while we are at this: multiprocessing by `fork` just have the exact same objects on the new process, while the Windows way have to start a new process from scratch, and serialize objects so they are sent to the new process - it is not a "check"- it is that the "ghost sibling" of DProcess can't be deserialized by Pickle, since it does not exist on the other process.

Now, if you really want to have your classes inheriting from Thread or Process, you might just create the two classes, and use a factory function to select which you want.
While it would be trivial to have a function to create both similar classes and put then in a list or global dictionary, Pickle does not like that much: it needs the instances or classes to be pickled to be declared at the top level of the module (so that the qualified name to a class can get you back to the class constructor). And even there, no need to repeat code - you can just use a mixin class with whatever is your common code, and with two lines you create your ProcessDworker and ThreadDWorker (which can then be selected by a factory function):

```py
    
    
class Stub:
    """just needed in case some linter or static checker complain about
    these methods not being present in the mixin
    
    But you could also declare these as @abstractmethod 
    to ensure just a proper class incorporating Thread or Process can
    be instantiated
    """
    
    def run(self): pass
    def start(self): pass
    def join(self): pass

class DProcessMixin(Stub):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        # whatever code you need to setup yoru worker - like creating queues, and such
        ...
        super().__init__(self, ...)
    
    ...
    
class ThreadDprocess(DProcessMixin, threading.Thread):
    queue_class = threading.Queue
    pass

class ProcessDProcess(DProcessMixin, threadng.
    queue_class = multiprocessing.Queue
    pass


def DProcess(*args, backend, **kwargs):
    if backend == "process":
        cls = ProcessDProcess
    elif backend == "thread":
        cls = ThreadDprocess
    return cls(*args, **kwargs)
```

And finally, if you really want to put a metaclass in play, just perceive that the `__call__` method in the metaclass is in the same position as this  `Dprocess` factory function on the last example. If you pre-create both classes and actually cache them, and set them both with a realname in the module `globals`  it would work. But if yu go back to your "cache" you can see it is bogus: it can't even actually "cache" information for more than one class in the same metaclass: your cache should have the class name as key, and as value hten you might have anoter dictionary holding the "name, bases, namespace" valus for each class. By the way, you are also confusing the `cls` arg passed to the the metaclass `__new__` with the class itself - that is also wrong. In short: I don't think you understand enough of the workings of the class mechanism to build code around that, and since your problem seems to be trivialy resolved by composition alone, it should be a no go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm sure, it is easier to build such a pattern using a factory method. I wanted to learn to use "metaclasses" using the above code. 
Comments: "your "cache" you can see it is bogus": This is because I removed a part of the code to make sure the question only focuses on the issue. Anyway, I've updated it to the original code now.

Comment: Yes - the cache looks much better now. Still, the "cls" value you store there is the metaclass itself, not the created class.